# File.ReadAllText and after File.WriteAllText

Tags: c#, file

My questions is, when i run this code its tell  me on "File.WriteAllText" line   procedure.pas is using by another program.

```
script = File.ReadAllText(Application.StartupPath + "\\Procedure.pas");
decryptedstring = Crypter.Decrypt(script, sSecretKey);

decryptedstring = decryptedstring.Replace("_" + Firma + "_", "_" + txtFirma.Text + "_");
decryptedstring = decryptedstring.Replace("_" + DonemNo + "_", "_" + txtDonemNo.Text + "_");
decryptedstring = decryptedstring.Replace("FIRMNR=" + Firma + " ", "FIRMNR=" + txtFirma.Text + " ");
encryptedstring = Crypter.Encrypt(decryptedstring, sSecretKey);
File.WriteAllText(Application.StartupPath + "\\Procedure.pas", encryptedstring);
```

Comment: Do you have write permissions to the Application,StartupPath ?

Comment: Put a breakpoint before WriteAllText and use Windows Resource Monitor to check who is using this file - just for curiosity...

Comment: I would guess that, the file you are trying to write too, is being used by another program?! :/

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the file you are writing is opened with a shared lock that allows reading data by other processes but does not allow writing. So when you are opening the file for write, it fails with the exception although the file was opened by another process the whole time.

See [FileShare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) enumeration for details on this.